# Process hollowing throws error 5 - access is denied

Tags: c, winapi, windbg, portable-executable

(My apologies in advance is some important info is missing. I didn't really know what to include. So if anyone wants me to add any information, just let me know and ill do my best. Thank you all!)

I tried to implement a process hollowing (RunPE) technique following this tutorial, in combination with my own knowledge, in C:

https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-injection-process-injection/process-hollowing-and-pe-image-relocations

Basically, I create a process at a suspended state, find it's PEB, then it's Image base address, and Unmap it's memory.

Then I proceed to reading the source file (in my case notepad.exe), defining it's headers, etc...
And then writing everything, including the headers, sections, and patched bytes via the realocations table, into the memory of the old process (which was unmmaped).

Then, I just get the process's context and change it's eax register to the entry point of the new process, and resume the main thread.

I tried checking in WinDbg, and all the memory seems to be written properly.
But, when the main thread is resumed with eax being the entry point, this error is shown (in WinDbg):

```
(216c.3d84): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=02fc1860 ebx=030a4000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=76f35080 esp=02f6fe58 ebp=00000000 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart:
76f35080 833ddc69fe7600  cmp     dword ptr [ntdll!LdrDelegatedRtlUserThreadStart (76fe69dc)],0 ds:002b:76fe69dc=00000000
```

I would be happy to hear any ideas of how can I further debug it, because i'm quite new to it.

Below is my `main.c`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winternl.h>


typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* NtUnmapViewOfSection)(
    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    PVOID  BaseAddress
    );


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    printf("Creating process\r\n");

    LPSTARTUPINFOA si = (LPSTARTUPINFOA)calloc(1, sizeof(STARTUPINFOA));
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION pi = (LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)calloc(1, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Start process in suspended state
    if (!CreateProcessA
    (
        "C:\\Windows\\sysWOW64\\calc.exe",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        si,
        pi
    ))
    {
        printf("Error with CreateProcessA - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (!pi->hProcess)
    {
        printf("Error creating process - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE hDestProcess = pi->hProcess;

    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION* pbi = (PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION*)calloc(1, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION));
    DWORD retLen = 0;

    // Find PEB
    if (NtQueryInformationProcess(hDestProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, pbi, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &retLen))
    {
        printf("Error finding peb - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("PEB address: %p\n", pbi->PebBaseAddress);

    DWORD pebImageBaseOffset = (DWORD)pbi->PebBaseAddress + 0x8;

    LPVOID destImageBase = 0;
    SIZE_T bytesRead;

    // Find image base by PEB's offset 0x8
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(hDestProcess, (LPCVOID)pebImageBaseOffset, &destImageBase, 0x4, &bytesRead))
    {
        printf("Error getting process's image base - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Process image base: %p\n", destImageBase);

    // Read other exe file
    HANDLE sourceFile =
        CreateFileA("C:\\Windows\\sysWOW64\\notepad.exe", GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
    DWORD sourceFileSize = GetFileSize(sourceFile, NULL);
    DWORD fileBytesRead = 0;
    LPVOID sourceFileStart = (LPVOID)malloc(sourceFileSize);
    ReadFile(sourceFile, sourceFileStart, sourceFileSize, &fileBytesRead, NULL);

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER sourceDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)sourceFileStart;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS sourceNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)sourceFileStart + sourceDosHeader->e_lfanew);
    SIZE_T sourceSize = sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;

    // Get the NtUnmapViewOfSection function and unmap the memory
    NtUnmapViewOfSection NtUnmapViewOfSectionFunc =
        (NtUnmapViewOfSection)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtUnmapViewOfSection");

    if (NtUnmapViewOfSectionFunc == NULL)
    {
        printf("Problem finding NtUnmapViewOfSection - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (NtUnmapViewOfSectionFunc(hDestProcess, destImageBase))
    {
        printf("Problem unmapping process virtual memory");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Memory unammped\n");

    PVOID newDestImageBase =
        VirtualAllocEx(hDestProcess, NULL, sourceSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    printf("New allocated image base: %p\n", newDestImageBase);

    sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase = (DWORD)destImageBase;

    // Write headers
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hDestProcess, newDestImageBase, sourceFileStart, sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL))
    {
        printf("Problem writing headers - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceSection = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(sourceNtHeaders);
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceSectionOld = sourceSection;

    // Save the reloc table pointer for later
    DWORD sourceRelocTableRaw;

    // Write sections
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        if (!sourceSection->PointerToRawData)
            continue;

        PVOID destSectionAddr = (PVOID)((DWORD)newDestImageBase + sourceSection->VirtualAddress);
        PVOID sourceSectionAddr = (PVOID)((DWORD)sourceFileStart + sourceSection->PointerToRawData);

        printf("Writing %s section to %p\r\n", sourceSection->Name, destSectionAddr);

        if (!WriteProcessMemory(hDestProcess, destSectionAddr, sourceSectionAddr, sourceSection->SizeOfRawData, NULL))
        {
            printf("Problem writing sections - %d", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        if (memcmp(sourceSection->Name, ".reloc", 6) == 0)
        {
            sourceRelocTableRaw = sourceSection->PointerToRawData;
        }

        sourceSection++;
    }

    // Getting the difference between the real based address and the preferred base address, for relocations
    DWORD deltaImageBase = (DWORD)newDestImageBase - sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;

    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY relocTable = sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC];
    DWORD relocOffset = 0;

    while (relocOffset < relocTable.Size)
    {
        PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION relocBlock = (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)((DWORD)sourceFileStart + sourceRelocTableRaw + relocOffset);
        relocOffset += sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION);
        DWORD relocEntryCount = (relocBlock->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)) / sizeof(WORD);
        PWORD relocEntries = (PWORD)((DWORD)sourceFileStart + sourceRelocTableRaw + relocOffset);

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < relocEntryCount; i++)
        {
            relocOffset += sizeof(WORD);

            if (relocEntries[i] & 0xF000 == IMAGE_REL_BASED_ABSOLUTE)
            {
                // Skip this entry, since it represents an absolute address
                continue;
            }

            DWORD patchAddrRVA = relocBlock->VirtualAddress + (relocEntries[i] & 0x0FFF);
            DWORD patchedBuff = 0;
            
            if (!ReadProcessMemory(hDestProcess, (DWORD)newDestImageBase + patchAddrRVA, &patchedBuff, sizeof(DWORD), &bytesRead))
            {
                printf("Problem reading bytes to patch - %d", GetLastError());
                return 1;
            }

            // Add the difference between the actual image base and the preferred image base
            patchedBuff += deltaImageBase;

            if (!WriteProcessMemory(hDestProcess, (DWORD)newDestImageBase + patchAddrRVA, &patchedBuff, sizeof(DWORD), NULL))
            {
                printf("Problem writing patched bytes - %d", GetLastError());
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Relocation bytes patched\n");

    // Get context of the main thread
    LPCONTEXT context = (LPCONTEXT)malloc(sizeof(CONTEXT));;
    context->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_INTEGER;
    GetThreadContext(pi->hThread, context);

    // Change entry point
    DWORD newEntryPoint = (DWORD)newDestImageBase + sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
    context->Eax = newEntryPoint;
    
    printf("New entry point addr: %p\n", newEntryPoint);

    // Set the main thread context with eax containing the new entry point
    SetThreadContext(pi->hThread, context);

    // Finally, resume the main thread
    ResumeThread(pi->hThread);
    printf("Process main thread resumed");

    // Close handles
    CloseHandle(pi->hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi->hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Greatly appreciated!

Comment: `c0000005` this is Access violation, but not access denied

Comment: You're right, my mistake. any idea on how to resolve the problem anyway?

Comment: Start by reading [Structured Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling).

Comment: I read it. What's the next step?

Comment: Now that you know what a "first-chance exception" is you can continue debugging.

Comment: Yeah I apologize, but I do not understand how it helps me detect the problem really.

Comment: You detect the problem by initially ignoring first-chance exceptions. Your debugger helpfully informed you that *"This exception may be expected and handled"*.

Comment: But how can I handle it in my code? I start a different process. In the documantation it says that most of the times, the problem is not in my code even.

Comment: *"But how can I handle it in my code?"* - You aren't supposed to, and I didn't suggest that you did, either. Ignore first-chance exceptions **in the debugger** and move on, by typing `g` into WinDbg.

Comment: Oh okay I see. I did what u said, and now I get a second chance exception with the same error... and when I continue to di it, it just cycles, between first and second. Any idea on what Can i do next?

Comment: I assume that the problem is related to the unmapping of the memory. Because i think it might be unmapping the ntdll which gets loaded by default, and when the thread is resumed, ntdll isn't there. So I tried it without unmapping and I got a different error, which I think is realted to the relocations table patching.. Im not sure.

Comment: When you hit a second-chance exception, then that indicates an issue. You can type [`!analyze -v`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-analyze) to get extended exception information. That will, among others, tell you the attempted access (read/write/execute). Combine that with the CPU instruction that triggered the error, and you are on your way to understand what's wrong, and eventually how to fix it.

Comment: I must point out that you have called `NtQueryInformationProcess` to pass in the target process object handle. `destImageBase` must be the allocated PEB structure memory pointer. You need to replace `LPVOID destImageBase` with `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION destImageBase` or `_PEB destImageBase`. Then reference it in the `NtUnmapViewOfSection`.

Comment: im getting `destImageBase` by reading the memory in whatever is at `peb + 0x8` (which is a pointer to the image base addr. So it should be right. I mean, it is, otherwise the rest of the code wouldn't work.

Comment: And I think, my problem is, that when I use NtUnmapViewOfSection, it unmaps EVERYTHING, including all of the ntdll.dll module that is loaded by default. Therefore, the program access invalid, unmapped memory, so it crashes.
This is just my assumption. But anyways, any idea of how can i solve it? Maybe force the target process to load ntdll.dll after?

Comment: @nortain32 Have you checked the address of destImageBase? Here is the result of my running on C++.https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiSPL.png

Comment: @nortain32 I deleted some of the contents of the notepad .exe. The main thread is successfully suspended and resumed after modification.https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgj35.png

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT: "I deleted some of the contents of the notepad .exe." - unless we know how and why to do that exactly, this comment is useless. You made it work on your machine. We want it to work on our machines. If you write an answer and explain it, I'm willing to upvote.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I can explained this. `sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader` is not initialized, so the memory location it points to is unknown, which will inevitably cause errors. So I believe this will definitely cause problems with `virtualAllocEx`and `WriteProcessMemory`. And I saw many struct pointers converted. The space occupied by the target pointer type is undefined. Because of this, I had read access violation without deleting this section.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT
Did it work for you in CPP? also, was the target process notepad.exe and the process you "inject" was calc.exe? if so, it worked for me this way too. But only with these processes. If i switch them for example, i get the access violation 0x5. If I use cmd.exe as the injected process, it fails to run with 0x142. So i really have no idea what it is all about.
But anyways, Torrecto-MSFT, mind sharing your code?
What parts of notepad.exe you deleted? How? and why?

Comment: @nortain32 I'm still working on it and I'm trying not to deleted the content to prevent ambiguity. Currently I'm having problems writing headers, and `WriteProcessMemory` returns error 299. I'll let you know if there are some updates.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I kinda gave up on this and was satisfied with just having notepad.exe and calc.exe work, since i really have no idea and wanted to do different things. But keep me updated.

Answer (score 1):

**In the part of PEB**.

You have called `NtQueryInformationProcess` to pass in the target process object handle. `destImageBase` must be the allocated PEB structure memory pointer. You need to replace `LPVOID destImageBase` with `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION destImageBase`. Then reference it in the `NtUnmapViewOfSection`.

After modification：

```
 PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION  destImageBase;
 destImageBase.PebBaseAddress;
```

`sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader` is not initialized, so the memory location it points to is unknown, which will inevitably cause errors like **read violation**, etc.

After modification:

```
 PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 sourceNtHeaders =(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)malloc(sizeof(*sourceNtHeaders));
 IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 sourceSize;
 sourceSize=(sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader);
 SIZE_T szsz = sizeof(sourceSize.SizeOfImage);
```

**In the part of write headers**.

in `WriteProcessMemory`, `sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders` represents a structure type pointer that spans two blocks, so it returns a **299 error**.

Similarly, `PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` also need to initialize pointers and allocate memory blocks.

```
sourceSection= (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)malloc(sizeof(sourceSection));
(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)malloc(sourceSection->VirtualAddress);
sizeof(sourceSection->VirtualAddress);
```

**As for the write sections part**, I guess you haven't come this far yet. And this part of the code has not been completely corrected, even with reference to [process hollowing (RunPE)](https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-injection-process-injection/process-hollowing-and-pe-image-relocations) you posted, I can't fully understand.

For example, in `relocationBlock->BlockSize - sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)) / sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY)`,`BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY` is simply replaced by `WORD`. So I won't modify this part for now unless you will update it later.

**Here is the full code. Hope this helps.**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winternl.h>

typedef
NTSTATUS(WINAPI* pfnNtQueryInformationProcess)
(HANDLE ProcessHandle, ULONG ProcessInformationClass,
    PVOID ProcessInformation, UINT32 ProcessInformationLength,
    UINT32* ReturnLength);

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* NtUnmapViewOfSection)(
    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    PVOID  BaseAddress
    );


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    printf("Creating process\r\n");

    LPSTARTUPINFOA si = (LPSTARTUPINFOA)calloc(1, sizeof(STARTUPINFOA));
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION pi = (LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)calloc(1, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Start process in suspended state
    BOOL cpa = CreateProcessA
    (
        "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\calc.exe",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        si,
        pi
    );
    if (!cpa)
    {
        printf("Error with CreateProcessA - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (!pi->hProcess)
    {
        printf("Error creating process - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE hDestProcess = pi->hProcess;

    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION* pbi = (PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION*)calloc(1, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION));
    DWORD retLen = 0;
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll");
    pfnNtQueryInformationProcess NtQueryInformationProcess =
        (pfnNtQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(hModule, "NtQueryInformationProcess");
    // Find PEB
    if (NtQueryInformationProcess(hDestProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, pbi, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), (UINT32*) & retLen))
    {
        printf("Error finding peb - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("PEB address: %p\n", pbi->PebBaseAddress);

    DWORD pebImageBaseOffset = (DWORD)pbi->PebBaseAddress + 0x8;

    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION  destImageBase;
    destImageBase.PebBaseAddress;

    SIZE_T bytesRead;

    // Find image base by PEB's offset 0x8
    BOOL rc1 = ReadProcessMemory(hDestProcess, (LPCVOID)pebImageBaseOffset, &destImageBase, 0xD, &bytesRead);
    if (!rc1)
    {
        printf("Error getting process's image base - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Process image base: %p\n", destImageBase);

    // Read other exe file
    HANDLE sourceFile =
        CreateFileA("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\notepad.exe", GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);
    DWORD sourceFileSize = GetFileSize(sourceFile, NULL);
  
    DWORD fileBytesRead ;
    LPVOID sourceFileStart = malloc(sizeof(sourceFileSize));
    ReadFile(sourceFile, sourceFileStart, sourceFileSize, &fileBytesRead, NULL);

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER sourceDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)sourceFileStart;

     PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 sourceNtHeaders =(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)malloc(sizeof(*sourceNtHeaders));
     IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 sourceSize;
     sourceSize=(sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader);
     SIZE_T szsz = sizeof(sourceSize.SizeOfImage);
   
     sourceNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)((DWORD)sourceFileStart + sourceDosHeader->e_lfanew);
 
     LPVOID newDestImageBase =
        (LPVOID*)VirtualAllocEx(hDestProcess, 0, szsz, MEM_COMMIT| MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
     if (newDestImageBase == NULL)
     {
         printf("VirtualAllocEx error :%X\n", (BYTE*)newDestImageBase);
         
     }

    // Get the NtUnmapViewOfSection function and unmap the memory
    NtUnmapViewOfSection NtUnmapViewOfSectionFunc =
        (NtUnmapViewOfSection)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtUnmapViewOfSection");

    if (NtUnmapViewOfSectionFunc(hDestProcess, pi->hProcess) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Problem finding NtUnmapViewOfSection - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Memory unammped\n");

    printf("New allocated image base: %p\n", newDestImageBase);

    //szsz = (DWORD)(destImageBase = {});
    DWORD lpflOldProtect;
  
    // Write headers
 

    //VirtualProtectEx(hDestProcess, newDestImageBase, sizeof(sourceSize.SizeOfHeaders), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &lpflOldProtect);

   BOOL res2= WriteProcessMemory(hDestProcess, newDestImageBase, (LPCVOID)&szsz, sizeof(sourceSize.SizeOfHeaders), NULL);
    if (!res2)
    {
        printf("Problem writing headers - %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    //VirtualProtectEx(hDestProcess, newDestImageBase, sizeof(sourceSize.SizeOfHeaders), lpflOldProtect, &lpflOldProtect);
     sourceNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)malloc(sizeof(sourceNtHeaders));
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceSection = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(sourceNtHeaders);
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceSectionOld = sourceSection;
    sourceSection= (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)malloc(sizeof(sourceSection));
    (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)malloc(sourceSection->VirtualAddress);
    sizeof(sourceSection->VirtualAddress);
    // Save the reloc table pointer for later
    DWORD sourceRelocTableRaw = {};

    // Write sections
  //  for (int i = 0; i < sourceNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
  //  {
  //      if (!sourceSection->PointerToRawData)
  //          continue;

  //      PVOID destSectionAddr = (PVOID)((DWORD)newDestImageBase + sourceSection->VirtualAddress);
  //      sizeof(destSectionAddr);
  //destSectionAddr =
  //          (LPVOID*)VirtualAllocEx(hDestProcess, 0, 4, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  //      PVOID sourceSectionAddr = (PVOID)((DWORD)sourceFileStart + sourceSection->PointerToRawData);
  //      sizeof(sourceSectionAddr);
  //      printf("Writing %d section to %p\r\n", sourceSection->Name, destSectionAddr);
  //      SIZE_T ssection = sizeof(sourceSection->SizeOfRawData);
  //      VirtualProtectEx(hDestProcess, destSectionAddr, sizeof(ssection), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &lpflOldProtect);
  //      if (!WriteProcessMemory(hDestProcess, destSectionAddr,  &sourceSectionAddr, ssection, NULL))
  //      {
  //          printf("Problem writing sections - %d", GetLastError());
  //          return 1;
  //      }
  //      VirtualProtectEx(hDestProcess, destSectionAddr, sizeof(ssection), lpflOldProtect, &lpflOldProtect);

  //      if (memcmp(sourceSection->Name, (BYTE*)".reloc", 6) == 0)
  //      {
  //          sourceRelocTableRaw = sourceSection->PointerToRawData;
  //      }

  //      sourceSection++;
  //  }

  //  // Getting the difference between the real based address and the preferred base address, for relocations
  //  DWORD deltaImageBase = (DWORD)newDestImageBase - sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;

  //  IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY relocTable = sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC];
  //  DWORD relocOffset = 0;

  //  while (relocOffset < relocTable.Size)
  //  {
  //      
  //      PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION relocBlock = (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)((DWORD)sourceFileStart + sourceRelocTableRaw + relocOffset);
  //      relocOffset += sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION);
  //      SIZE_T rb = sizeof(relocBlock->SizeOfBlock);
  //      DWORD relocEntryCount = (rb - sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)) / sizeof(WORD);
  //      PWORD relocEntries = (PWORD)((DWORD)sourceFileStart + sourceRelocTableRaw + relocOffset);
  //      relocEntries = (PWORD)malloc(sizeof(relocEntries));

  //      for (DWORD i = 0; i < relocEntryCount; i++)
  //      {
  //          relocOffset += sizeof(WORD);

  //          if (relocEntries[i] & 0xF000 == IMAGE_REL_BASED_ABSOLUTE)
  //          {
  //              // Skip this entry, since it represents an absolute address
  //              continue;
  //          }
  //          
  //          PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION relocBlock = (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)malloc(sizeof(relocBlock));
  //          DWORD patchAddrRVA = relocBlock->VirtualAddress + (relocEntries[i] & 0x0FFF);
  //          LPVOID np = (LPVOID)sizeof((DWORD)newDestImageBase + patchAddrRVA);
  //          np =
  //              (LPVOID*)VirtualAllocEx(hDestProcess, 0, 4, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  //          DWORD patchedBuff = 0;
  //          //VirtualProtectEx(hDestProcess, (LPVOID)(sizeof((DWORD)newDestImageBase + patchAddrRVA)), sizeof((DWORD)newDestImageBase + patchAddrRVA), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &lpflOldProtect);

  //          BOOL btp=ReadProcessMemory(hDestProcess, (LPVOID)np, &patchedBuff, sizeof(DWORD), &bytesRead);
  //          if (!btp)
  //          {
  //              printf("Problem reading bytes to patch1 - %d", GetLastError());
  //              return 1;
  //          }
  //          //VirtualProtectEx(hDestProcess, (LPVOID)(sizeof((DWORD)newDestImageBase + patchAddrRVA)), sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &lpflOldProtect);
  //          // Add the difference between the actual image base and the preferred image base
  //          patchedBuff += deltaImageBase;

  //          if (!WriteProcessMemory(hDestProcess, (LPVOID)np, &patchedBuff, sizeof(DWORD), NULL))
  //          {
  //              printf("Problem writing patched bytes2 - %d", GetLastError());
  //              return 1;
  //          }
  //      }
  //  }

    printf("Relocation bytes patched\n");

    // Get context of the main thread
    LPCONTEXT context = (LPCONTEXT)malloc(sizeof(CONTEXT));;
    context->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_INTEGER;
    GetThreadContext(pi->hThread, context);

    // Change entry point
    DWORD newEntryPoint = (DWORD)newDestImageBase + sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
    context->Eax = newEntryPoint;

    printf("New entry point addr: %p\n", newEntryPoint);

    // Set the main thread context with eax containing the new entry point
    SetThreadContext(pi->hThread, context);

    // Finally, resume the main thread
    ResumeThread(pi->hThread);
    printf("Process main thread resumed");

    // Close handles
    CloseHandle(pi->hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi->hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand a few of the things you wrote.

Why should `destImageBase` be a `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION`? It's just an address that i'm reading, the image base. It worked fine.

As for the relocations part, i used `WORD` as it is the real data type of those fields.

Look at the code at the end of the artical - `BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY` and others are just a typedef created by the author.

But anyways, thank you for your efforts.