# C++ Game Pointer Address changes to Offsets not the value address

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, offset, pointer-address

I made a code that should give me the value of the pointer address. For that i "build" the address but the address is always only the offset of the pointer address. Cant figure out why i look in the internet they have it the same way but mine wont work.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;



DWORD GetModuleBaseAddress(TCHAR* lpszModuleName, DWORD pID) {
    DWORD dwModuleBaseAddress = 0;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pID); // make snapshot of all modules within process
    MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32 = { 0 };
    ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
 
    if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)) //store first Module in ModuleEntry32
    {
        do {
            if (_tcscmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0) // if Found Module matches Module we look for -> done!
            {
                dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD64)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                break;
            }
        } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)); // go through Module entries in Snapshot and store in ModuleEntry32
 
 
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    return dwModuleBaseAddress;
}
 
DWORD GetPointerAddress(HWND hwnd, DWORD gameBaseAddr, DWORD address, vector<DWORD> offsets)
{
    DWORD pID = NULL; // Game process ID
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pID);
    HANDLE phandle = NULL;
    phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
    std::cout<< GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    if (phandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || phandle == NULL);
    std::cout<< GetLastError()<<std::endl;
 
    DWORD offset_null = NULL;
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(gameBaseAddr + address), &offset_null, sizeof(offset_null), 0);
    DWORD pointeraddress = offset_null; // the address we need
    for (int i = 0; i < offsets.size() - 1; i++) // we dont want to change the last offset value so we do -1
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(pointeraddress + offsets.at(i)), &pointeraddress, sizeof(pointeraddress), 0);
        std::cout<< GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    }
    return pointeraddress += offsets.at(offsets.size() - 1); // adding the last offset
}



int main()
{

    HWND hwnd_AC = FindWindowA(NULL, "BloonsTD6");

    if (hwnd_AC != FALSE);
    DWORD pID = NULL;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd_AC, &pID);
    HANDLE phandle = NULL;
    phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
    if (phandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || phandle == NULL);

    
    DWORD gamebaseaddress1 = GetModuleBaseAddress(_T("GameAssembly.dll"), pID);

    DWORD moneyAddr = 0x035F9E18;
    vector<DWORD> moneyOffsets{ 0x198,0xF8,0x138,0x160,0x60,0x1A8,0xC8 };
    DWORD64 moneyPtrAddr = GetPointerAddress(hwnd_AC, gamebaseaddress1, moneyAddr, moneyOffsets);

    std::cout << "debugginfo: Value at offset = " << std::hex << moneyPtrAddr << std::endl;
    std::cout<< GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    }
```

The output is always the same:

160 (its the last offset i have in the code)

Comment: [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) has a return value, but the code doesn't seem to care much. That's curious.

Comment: Or any of the other API return values, for that matter. It is checking them, but ignoring the result of those checks.

Comment: What you mean checking for errors isn't enough, you have to handle them as well? :D

Comment: You can use `GetProcAddress`.Check Destination ImageBaseAddress: https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-injection-process-injection/process-hollowing-and-pe-image-relocations#destination-imagebaseaddress

Comment: @Chraydragon The symptom you described definitely suggests that `ReadProcessMemory()` is failing, leaving `pointeraddress` at its initial value of `offset_null` (0), so that `return pointeraddress += offsets.at(offsets.size() - 1);` is effectively just returning `offsets.at(offsets.size() - 1)` as-is. This would have easily been verified if you had used a debugger to check the behavior of the code.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  do you know how i can fix that?

Comment: @Chraydragon fix your code to pay attention to API return values. If an API fails, STOP WHAT YOU'RE DOING, don't keep going. The API failed for a reason, debug/log the failure to find out why, and act on it, don't just ignore it, as you are now. Maybe `OpenProcess()` failed to open the process. Maybe you are using bad offsets causing `ReadProcessMemory()` to read the wrong addresses. Who knows. You are not debugging/logging those actions, or acting on those failures if they happen.

Comment: @Chraydragon Using the `GetLastError()` helps you get error code when APIs fail.

Comment: So i tried with GetLastError() and the result was always Error 299 i looked it up but it just says that the Process was not completely completed. I also tried in python with pymem but same Error code 299. I dont know how to fix it i look some solitions up but they did not help me and i still habe the error

Comment: @Chraydragon 299 means Only partially complete a `ReadProcessMemory` or `WriteProcessMemory` request. Actually, in WriteProcessMemory the pointer that spans two blocks, so it returns a 299 error. I solved a similiar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049717/process-hollowing-throws-error-5-access-is-denied/76162510#76162510

Comment: @Chraydragon May I ask you to edit your code to a minimal reprouducible sample? I will   tested it until it can be compiled successfully.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT i edited the code like i have it and compiled it. I dont know if the pointers saty the same and the addresses and offsets. I will look at the link you send and try to solve it and kepp updates here.

Comment: @Chraydragon Right now I know you wanted to Implement game reverse. `ReadProcessMemory` returns 299. Why? The game"BloonsTD6" is the other process which means reading memory across processes. That asks the processes' all data in the base address and memory is read-accessible. And I saw the way you get the address of module,it gets a list of the modules belonging to the specified process NOT address. You need to use `GetModuleHandleA` and print it. But this address is not baseaddress. We need to know the offset.

Comment: @Chraydragon So I just can give 2 suggestions: one use some tools like:x64dbg, cheatengine to get the offset and base address. Two, create a new process and use its `pi` to get the PEB. we also know that the BaseAddressis 8 bytes away from the PEB. So that's will be simple just as the link i sent.